# Always the same size of image on all screens

Tags: javascript, screen, resolution, screen-resolution, dpi

I need that square image always be the same size on any screen (including mobile, tablet...). So if I take the ruler and measure image on any screen it have to be 5mm for example. It must be in JavaScript.

I wonder if the size of that image depends only of screen's DPI or it depends of screen resolution also? If in JavaScript I detect screen's DPI (and resolution if needed) is there any formula (or some JavaScript function) to calculate image size to get always the same result?

In the end, can I define image size in some unit which will ensure image to be always the same?

I asked the question here because it is connected to JavaScript, if you think that it is more suitable for some other forum please let me know.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want an image always to have a fixed absolute physical size. There is no way to achieve that. You can define a width with absolute units like inch, centimeter or millimeter, but the rendered result differs from one screen to another.

Every browser has set internally `1 inch = 96px`, and with that base all other units are calculated. So only if a screen has a physical pixel-size of exactly 25.4 / 96 = `0.26458 mm`
an element having width set to 5mm is really 5mm.

But the absolute physical size of a pixel differs widely on different screens and is not detectable by javascript.

**EDIT** According to your comment: **Yes** it is possible with your own screen. You can display an element with a width set to 200mm and measure the real width on screen in mm with a ruler. The quotient 200 / your_measurement gives you a conversion factor.

If you now want to set a width to a fixed value you have to multiply that value with the factor.

Display following file and measure the width of the red quadrat:

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {width: 200mm; height: 200mm; margin: 50px; background-color: red;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The conversion factor is valid for all absolute units you want to use.

With some interaction of a user you can calibrate a users screen as they did on the ZEISS page you linked to. The user has to compare the element on screen against a fixed width (e.g. width of a credit card = 54mm). Since here the user is fixed and the code does the measurement, calculation of the factor is contrariwise: `conversion factor f = code_result / 54`.

I have made a [FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/qxw25gzx/12/) with 0.5mm-steps to get more accuracy.

Comment: Is it possible to do some kind of calibration and according to the result calculate image size (like monitor screen calibration in [this test](http://www.zeiss.com/vision-care/en_de/better-vision/better-vision-with-zeiss/zeiss-online-vision-screening-check.html))? In this test, size of letter "E" is calculated according to the calibration.

Comment: So, if I understand right (according to example test that I posted in comment), I need to show credit card with defined width of 5.4cm (54mm) and on plus and minus buttons decrease i.e increase size in code for 1mm, when user measure 54mm on screen with his ruler I need to calculate real size for user using (54/user's result)*5 (to show 5mm)?

Comment: @mixerowsky If the user should hold a credit card on screen to compare the size its just contrariwise, because not user but your code does the measurement: conversion factor `f = code_result / 54`. Then f * 5 to show 5mm.

Comment: So, after user gets 54mm on his screen I see how much is it millimeters in code and calculate the size like you mentioned above (`f = code_result/54, f*5`)?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I made a [FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/qxw25gzx/12/) with 0.5mm-steps to get more accuracy.